# Spark scala iterative loop to fetch attributes

Tags: dataframe, scala, loops, apache-spark, hierarchy

I have a requirement in which source is a json payload which might or may not have certain attributes in levels. Let's say a product might have 3 levels and few products might have 5 levels. Accordingly, we will receive 3 and 5 levels of attributes in source json.

Input:-

+-----+--------+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-------+

|l1 id |l1 name|l2 id|l2 name|l3 id|l3 name|l4 id|l4 name|l5 id|l5 name|

+-----+--------+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-------+-----+-------+

|0    | root   |1    | a     |2    | b     |     |       |     |       |

|0    | root   |1    | a     |3    | c     |4    | d     |5    |e      |

---

Expected Output :-

+---+------+----+

|id |parent|name|

+---+------+----+

|0  |      |root|

|1  |0     |a   |

|2  |1     |b   |

|3  |1     |c   |

|4  |3     |d   |

|5  |4     |e   |

+---+------+----+

Like above, some products may have multiple levels as well. Basically, it's an hierarchy data coming in multiple levels. How should we process them in spark-scala ? We are planning to create a  hierarchy table (similar to employee - manager example of hierarchy) where we store the child records with parent id reference.

Below is what I trying, but I am unable to name a dataframe dynamically. It's throwing error.

If a product has 3 levels, then loop should break after 3 levels and if a product has 5 levels then loop should break at 5th level.

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("Oblite_Analysis")
  .getOrCreate()

val sc = spark.sparkContext
//sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
import spark.implicits._

var args: Array[String] = new Array[String](3)
args(0) = "C:\\Users\\Saravana_kumaar_Rang\\Downloads\\oblite.json"

val src_df_0 = spark.read.json(args(0))
    var i=0

var df = "src_df_" + i
println(df)

  while(true) {
    if (df.columns.contains("componentSelections"))
    {
      val src_df1 = src_df
        .withColumn("exploded_cs1", explodeHasColumn(src_df, "componentSelections"))
        .select(
          col("id").alias("lvl1_id"),
          col("name").alias("lvl1_name"),
          col("exploded_cs1.id").alias("lvl2_id"),
          col("exploded_cs1.components"))

      println("2nd level")
      src_df1.show(false)

      val src_df2 = src_df1
        .withColumn("exploded_cp1",explodeHasColumn(src_df1, "components"))
        .select(col("lvl1_id"),
          col("lvl1_name"),
          col("lvl2_id"),
          col("exploded_cp1.component.id").alias("lvl3_id"),
          col("exploded_cp1.component.name").alias("lvl3_name"),
          col("exploded_cp1.component.componentSelections")
        )

      println("3rd level")
      src_df2.show(false)
    }
    else
      { break }
  }
```

Comment: can you please some input and expected output ?

Comment: @Srinivas - I have updated the question with sample input and output. Kindly help !